# How to add a custom HTML tag in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

i know vscode has custom snippet like this

```json
    {
        "foo": {
            "prefix": "foo",
            "body": [
                "<foo FIELD='${1|one,two,three|}'></foo>"
            ],
            "description": "a custom html tag with special prop"
        }
    }
```

but in fact, that is not good enough, how to show every different attribute what is its meaning?

Is there anything not so difficult ways can i do that? i try TextMate or VSCode plugin its so hard for me.

If there is no, please just tell me, I will continue to try hard.

Comment: what do you mean with: `show the meaning of different choices`

Comment: @rioV8 , sorry about my word because my native language is not English, that means such as:
```html
<input type="text">
```
type have different choices: button, checkbox, file.

Comment: how to show every different attribute, what is its meaning?

Comment: there is a difference between `meaning` and `possible values`. what is wrong with typing a choice list, you want a custom tag, who should type all the possible choices: **YOU** because no one else knows it

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but `Custom Data Extension` is what you're probably looking for.

- [Github Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-custom-data)
- [Custom Data Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-data-extension)
- [Blog Post with examples](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/02/24/custom-data-format)

You can create `my-types.html-data.json` and achieve full completion for custom tags and attributes, as well as potential values.

You can do this by either generating it dynamically with your custom extension or adding your custom VS Code settings.